# Embed AngularJS based app into cocos2d-js project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I've existing AngularJS based web app. It is supposed to be like a game portal, so that user can choose which game he wants to play.
The games are written with cocos2d-js.

Are there any restrictions/rules to follow to embed AngularJS into cocos2d-js project?
My concern is that cocos2d is featured as game framework. Does it suitable for a regular web app/site.

Just it is nice to hear your opinions.